# How can i insert the tableau file(chart) in my own android app?

Tags: tableau-api

I am using tableau to create a chart after done the file how can I insert that chart in my own android app.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed you chart in a webpage which you can show in your android app using a WebView component.

There is extensive documentation on how to embed Tableau views, please go through [Tableau Documentation](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/embed.html).